# Read Dynamic JSON Property

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

So I'm currently using JSON.NET in Visual Studio to parse my JSON since using deserialization is too slow for what I'm trying to do. I'm pulling stock information from TD Ameritrade and can request multiple stocks at the same time. The JSON result below is from pulling only 1. As you can see, the first line is "TQQQ". If I were to pull more than one stock, I'd have "TQQQ", then "CEI" in separate blocks representing different objects.

Under normal deserialization, I could just say to deserialize a dictionary and it would put them into the dictionary accordingly with whatever class I had written for it to populate. However, since I need to parse line by line, is there a clean way of being able to tell when I've arrived to the next object?

I could say to keep track of the very last field and then add the next line (the next ticker's name) to dictionary, but that seems a little hacky.

I don't think any VB code is necessary besides the initial startup of creating a new JSONReader.

```
{
  "TQQQ": {
    "assetType": "ETF",
    "symbol": "TQQQ",
    "description": "ProShares UltraPro QQQ",
    "bidPrice": 54.59,
    "bidSize": 200,
    "bidId": "Q",
    "askPrice": 54.6,
    "askSize": 8000,
    "askId": "Q",
    "lastPrice": 54.6,
    "lastSize": 100,
    "lastId": "P",
    "openPrice": 51.09,
    "highPrice": 54.6,
    "lowPrice": 50.43,
    "bidTick": " ",
    "closePrice": 48.92,
    "netChange": 5.68,
    "totalVolume": 14996599,
    "quoteTimeInLong": 1540493136946,
    "tradeTimeInLong": 1540493136946,
    "mark": 54.6,
    "exchange": "q",
    "exchangeName": "NASDAQ",
    "marginable": true,
    "shortable": true,
    "volatility": 0.02960943,
    "digits": 4,
    "52WkHigh": 73.355,
    "52WkLow": 38.6568,
    "nAV": 0,
    "peRatio": 0,
    "divAmount": 0,
    "divYield": 0,
    "divDate": "2016-12-21 00:00:00.0",
    "securityStatus": "Normal",
    "regularMarketLastPrice": 54.6,
    "regularMarketLastSize": 1,
    "regularMarketNetChange": 5.68,
    "regularMarketTradeTimeInLong": 1540493136946,
    "delayed": true
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm or maybe https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm

Comment: Neither one, unfortunately. I've gone through both. Issue is knowing when to differentiate when a new object begins. Atm I'm just reading until the last property then adding the next line to dictionary. Really hacky.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Takes me 25ms to JObject.Parse(YourJson). How fast do you want it?

Comment: Then you will probably need a custom parser. You can probably split the string by  `'{', '}'` and parse the separate parts.

Comment: @CruleD as I said, the reflection process is too slow. I'm currently using a custom parser as recommended by Slai and it is processing it almost 3x faster now. Using JObject.Parse is twice as slow compared to using JSonTextReader and reading line by line.

Comment: So it takes 8ms?

Comment: `JSonTextReader` still has a lot of overhead, compared to completely custom parser. If it needs to be even faster, customizing the .NET [`JavaScriptObjectDeserializer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web.Extensions/Script/Serialization/JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.cs,f52801a35f3056a1) or other parsing code might be another option.

Comment: @CruleD Custom parsing takes 5ms. JSON.NET takes 25ms. JObject.Parse takes 11ms. I just need the fastest solution possible since this is dealing with realtime data and how quickly we can get it prepared and ready to be worked with. The only reason I'm even asking about something else on top of custom is because it doesn't seem very maintainable as opposed to serialization, but it's looking like that's just the tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a clean way of being able to tell when I've arrived at the next object?*

Yes, assuming you are using a [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) you can look at the [`TokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm) property and check whether it is [`StartObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm).  This corresponds to the opening braces `{` in the JSON.  There is also an [`EndObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonToken.htm) token type corresponding to the closing braces `}`, which will probably also be useful depending on how your code is written.

Typical usage pattern is something like this:

```
If reader.TokenType == TokenType.StartObject Then
    While reader.Read() AndAlso reader.TokenType <> JsonToken.EndObject
        ' process properties of the JSON object
    End While
End If
```